# Getting different array when run the for loop

Tags: reactjs

```js
const fetchData = async (e) => {
    
const arr = []
const newres = await axios.get(`https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings/?tag=${tag}&created_at_min=${minCreate}&created_at_max=${maxCreate}&page=${page}&limit=200`, {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "aftership-api-key": `${apiKey}`
    },
       /*  responseType: "blob" */
})
const res = await newres.data.data.trackings

arr.push(newres.data.data.trackings)
        
const pageNumber = newres.data.data.count/200;
const exactPage = Math.ceil(pageNumber);
      
for(let i=1; i<=exactPage; i++) {
    let newarr = []
    let n = await axios.get(`https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings/?tag=${tag}&created_at_min=${minCreate}&created_at_max=${maxCreate}&page=${i}&limit=200`, {
        headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "aftership-api-key": `${apiKey}`
        },
    })
    const arrr = n.data.data.trackings
    res.concat(arrr)
    console.log(i);
}
```

I'm trying to merge all the array into 1 object that we can download to CSV but all the array comes separately. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example of how to merge arrays:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const arr = [];
  let a = [11, 12, 23];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let b = [i,i*7];
    a = a.concat(b);
  }
  console.log(a);
};
```

in your code I think that you need to change:

```
res.concat(arrr)
```

to:

```
res = res.concat(arrr)
```

and change res from const to let

Note:
The concat() method is used to merge arrays.